# Hive query result based on header record

Tags: hive

I have a signle file like below which is contains the data combined from 4 different files into a single file from the source system.

The NEWFILE= is the separator of the data. For example all the data after the line NEWFILE=STUDENT and till the line NEWFILE=SUBJECT belongs to STUDENT file.
The issue is we don't have any pattern to separate the records of each file.
Also the source system cannot separate the file into 4 files.

I need to load this single input file and separate the records as per the header of the record.

What i did is loaded the data into a Hive table and tried the ROW_NUMBER & Random function.

I thought of using the ROW_NUMBER function to identify the row of each header and then filter the records in between the header rows, but ROW_NUMBER function output is not same as actual line order of the file. Due to this a row belonging to STUDENT may be assigned to SUBJECT.

I can't use the random function as it also doesn't give the actual row number

The file content data is given below

```
NEWFILE=STUDENT
100 XYZ
101 ABC
102 DEF
NEWFILE=SUBJECT
1 ENGLISH
2 MATHS
NEWFILE=TEACHERS
110 AAAAAAAA
111  BBBBBBB
222  CCCCCCC
333  DDDDDD
NEWFILE=CLASSES
1 CLASS-1
2 CLASS-2
```

Please advise how can I achieve my the desired output.

Comment: The actual data in the file is in separate lines, but it is not showing up correctly in the above section. Trying again to paste it in the comment section.

Comment: Remove the picture and put a text sample instead. Select the text and apply ctrl+k in order to format it as code

Comment: ctrl+k goes for the whole text, not just the first line. Check out the edited post.

Comment: Thanks Dudu, i removed the link and pasted the file content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create external table myfile (rec string)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
tblproperties ('serialization.last.column.takes.rest'='true')    
;
```

---

```
select      rec
           ,ifn
           ,ifn_newfile_seq

           ,row_number () over
            (
                partition by    ifn_newfile_seq
                order by        boif
            )   as ifn_newfile_rec_seq


from       (select  rec
                   ,input__file__name               as ifn
                   ,block__offset__inside__file     as boif

                   ,count(case when rec like 'NEWFILE=%' then 1 end) over
                    (
                        partition by    input__file__name
                        order by        block__offset__inside__file
                    ) as ifn_newfile_seq


            from    myfile
            ) l
;
```

---

```
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| rec              | ifn                                          | ifn_newfile_seq | ifn_newfile_rec_seq |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| NEWFILE=STUDENT  | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 1               | 1                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 100 XYZ          | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 1               | 2                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 101 ABC          | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 1               | 3                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 102 DEF          | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 1               | 4                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| NEWFILE=SUBJECT  | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 2               | 1                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 1 ENGLISH        | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 2               | 2                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 2 MATHS          | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 2               | 3                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| NEWFILE=TEACHERS | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 3               | 1                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 110 AAAAAAAA     | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 3               | 2                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 111  BBBBBBB     | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 3               | 3                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 222  CCCCCCC     | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 3               | 4                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 333  DDDDDD      | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 3               | 5                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| NEWFILE=CLASSES  | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 4               | 1                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 1 CLASS-1        | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 4               | 2                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
| 2 CLASS-2        | file:/home/cloudera/local_db/myfile/file.txt | 4               | 3                   |
+------------------+----------------------------------------------+-----------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Dudu. This really helps. I am having issues in my cluster and  couldn't run the queries. I will try and get back to you in case of any questions/issues.

Comment: Hi Dudu, I tried to implement the above logic in HiveContext in Spark, but I am getting error as INPUT__FILE__NAME couldn't be resolved. Do I need to change anything in the commands? Please advise.

Comment: @Nat, Spark does not support `input__file__name` and `block__offset__inside__file`. `input__file__name`  can be replaced by `input_file_name()` but I'm not aware for a replacement for `block__offset__inside__file`. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html